# Как подсчитать количество данных в столбце?

Tags: sqlalchemy

У меня есть функция для подсчета зарегистрированных пользователей:

```
async def count_registration_status():
    _session_maker: sessionmaker = session_maker
    async with _session_maker() as session:
        async with session.begin():
            result = await session.execute(func.count(User.registration_status).filter(text('Зарегистрирован')))
    return result.scalar()
```

Проблема в том, что в терминале появляется ошибка:

> sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Executable SQL or text() construct expected, got <sqlalchemy.sql.elements.FunctionFilter object at 0x7ff409686950>.